# How to clump hair particles from its root?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

How can I achieve No. 2?
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Clump -1? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/children.html

Comment: thanks, can't believe it's that easy, guess I need to read more on blender's manual.

Comment: well, I don't use the manual often as it's a little bit cryptic, I prefer youtube tutorials, anyway, nice to see I gave the solution (I don't even use Hairs ah ah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Clump -1 as explained by the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/children.html